# Can't disable NMI watchdog on Debian Buster in vmware context - couldn't write to kernel, unknown error 524

Tags: debian, boot, virtual-machine, nmi

Following [instructions](https://www.pcsuggest.com/disable-nmi-watchdog-linux/), I want to disable the NMI watchdog on boot.

```
sudo sh -c "echo '0' > /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog"
```

However:

```
Couldn't write '0' to 'kernel/nmi_watchdog': Unknown error 524
```

How to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer required or possible on Virtual Machines as NMI watchdog requires access to real hardware.

The "Unknown error 524" is the error code for ENOTSUPP: Operation not supported.

The kernel commit that introduced this can be found here:
https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20170831073054.997264122@linutronix.de/